# Vuex getters are not updated after store re-hydration from persistent storage

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, local-storage, electron, vuex

I'm facing a weird issue with my Electron + Vue setup.

**CONDITIONS:** Electron + Vue (I used a [boilerplate](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue)) + [vuex-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist) (also tried [vuex-persistedstate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate) and [vuex-persistfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistfile)).

**PROBLEM:** Vuex getters remain 0/null/'' when the store is being rehydrated. How do I know that? If the local storage is clean (I launch the app for the first time), first mutations update state (getters return correct values) and I can see an object being added to the browser's local storage. When the app is **restarted**, however, mutations trigger state and local storage update just like before, **BUT** getters remain empty/default. Below getter returns an empty array.

[image]

**SETUP:** I have an app that works with 3rd party API: gets data, calculates stuff and sends some data back. API also requires authorization. Below is my Vuex structure.

Part of my state object...

```
const state = {
  token: '',
  projects: [],
  work_packages: [],
  timeEntriesLocal: []
}
```

...and one of my getters:

```
const getters = {
  todayLog () {
    function sameDay (d1, d2) {
      return d1.getFullYear() === d2.getFullYear() &&
        d1.getMonth() === d2.getMonth() &&
        d1.getDate() === d2.getDate()
    }
    var entries = state.timeEntriesLocal
    var todayEntries = []
    entries.forEach(element => {
      var date = element.spentOn
      var today = new Date()
      if (sameDay(date, today)) {
        todayEntries.push(element)
      }
    })
    return todayEntries
  }
}
```

It returns entries from an array that are due to "today".

timeEntriesLocal is filled with this method:

```
addTimeEntry () {
  let entry = {
    id: this.$store.state.UserData.timeEntriesLocal.length + 1,
    project: this.getItemById(this.$store.state.UserData.current.project_id, this.$store.state.UserData.projects),
    spentOn: new Date(),
    comment: this.comment,
    activityId: this.activityId,
    workPackage: this.getItemById(this.$store.state.UserData.current.work_package_id, this.$store.state.UserData.work_packages),
    hours: this.precisionRound(this.$store.state.UserData.duration / 60 / 60, 2),
    published: false,
    loading: false,
    infoMessage: ''
  }

  this.$store.commit('ADD_LOCAL_ENTRY', entry)
}
```

And lastly here's the mutation that I have just used above:

```
ADD_LOCAL_ENTRY (state, entry) {
  state.timeEntriesLocal.unshift(entry)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The changes in `timeEntriesLocal` are not being picked up, since you're changing the length of the Array. This is a limitation of JavaScript covered in [Common Gotchas](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating) section of the docs. A way to go around it is also covered in [Vuex`s docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules):

> **Mutations Follow Vue's Reactivity Rules**
>
> Since a Vuex store's state is made reactive by Vue, when we mutate the state, Vue components
>   observing the state will update automatically. This also means Vuex
>   mutations are subject to the same reactivity caveats when working with
>   plain Vue:
>
> 1. Prefer initializing your store's initial state with all desired fields
>      upfront.
> 2. When adding new properties to an Object, you should either:
>
>    - `Use Vue.set(obj, 'newProp', 123)`, or
>    - Replace that Object with a fresh one. For example, using the object
>        spread syntax we can write it like this: `state.obj = { ...state.obj, newProp: 123 }`

So in your exmample, to make the Vue (Vuex) detect these changes, you can do something like:

```
ADD_LOCAL_ENTRY (state, entry) {
    state.timeEntriesLocal.unshift(entry);
    Vue.set(state, 'timeEntriesLocal', state.timeEntriesLocal);
}
```